# Extracting a API GET Request By Parsing JSON String

Tags: javascript, json, api

https://www.codeply.com/go/Dfsq1LcxTM

I am attempting to take a user's postal code to request the representatives of the locality. For troubleshooting purposes, I am attempting to log the console of both the postal code and the url including the postal code.

HTML

```
<div id="form">
<form type="text" class="form-inline" role="form">
  <label for="address" name="postalcode">Enter an address or postal code</label>
  <input id="search" placeholder="Enter an address or postal code" type="text">
  <button id="go">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Find
  </button>
</form>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#go").click(function(){

  var searchWord = $("#search").val();
  var url = "https://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/"+searchWord+"/?format=apibrowser";
  console.log(searchWord);
  console.log(url);
})

});
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong. Any idea what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the JavaScript when the submit button is clicked.

Then the form submits and a new page is loaded.

Under common browser settings, the Console is wiped.

---

You need to prevent the form submission. Call `preventDefault` on the event object.

In general, you should bind to submit events rather than click events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchWord = $("#search").val();
        var url = "https://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/" + searchWord + "/?format=apibrowser";
        console.log(searchWord);
        console.log(url);
    });

});
```

---

Asides:

> ```
> <div id="form">
> ```

Using an HTML element type as an ID is confusing at the best of times, then it is the id of an element of a different type: doubly so.

> ```
> <form type="text" class="form-inline" role="form">
> ```

There is no `type` attribute on a form element.

A form element is intrinsically a form. There is no point in using the role attribute to make it act like a form.

Comment: Thank you! The solution you provided works great. When I attempt to plug the solution into my project, I get two persistant errors:
1. An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can remove its sandboxing.
2. The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.

Any clue as to why this would be the case? (For reference: https://www.codeply.com/go/Dfsq1LcxTM  Try a postal code like K2H6G7)

Comment: @SeanMichaelConway — I can't reproduce that. I suspect it is caused by a browser extension.

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to get it to work on click? If so, remove the ready function that's wrapping your listener.

So if you just leave it like this:

```
   $("#go").click(function(){
     var searchWord = $("#search").val();
     var url = "https://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/"+searchWord+"/?format=apibrowser";
     console.log(searchWord);
     console.log(url);
})
```

it should produce what you want in the console.

Comment: Removing the ready event handler definitely will not help. It *might* make things worse if the `<script>` element appears before the button in the DOM (so the button wouldn't exist when the search is made to find it so the click event handler can be bound).